# Python hashlib хеш сущности

Tags: python, python-3.x, хеширование, hashlib

Нужно из инпута получить строку вида "\xF0\x9F\x98\x80" (это смайлик в utf-8) и получить хеш, но не строки, а самой сущности, как это можно сделать?

Например,  имеет хеш 34722ef0267ceda14f0e2b756b83e85d6e79e458967895e72b07f87da7c0e275. Если захешировать "\xF0\x9F\x98\x80", то получим не тот результат, т. к. это хеш строки, а не сущности.

Comment: Где и как вы получили этот хеш?

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что задача сводится к тому, чтобы сырой ввод `\xF0\x9F\x98\x80` декодировать в , чтобы потом уже взять хэш?

Comment: @nomnoms12, да.

Answer (score 1):

```py
s = r'\xf0\x9f\x98\x80'
hex_s = s.replace(r'\x', '')               # f09f9880
smile = bytearray.fromhex(hex_s).decode()  #
```

**UPD** на [комментарий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1246369/python-hashlib-%D1%85%D0%B5%D1%88-%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8/1246383?noredirect=1#comment2188206_1246383):

```py
def stdin_hash():
    raw = input('Ввод: ')
    hex_s = raw.replace(r'\x', '')
    text = bytearray.fromhex(hex_s)
    hash_object = hashlib.sha256(text)
    hex_dig = hash_object.hexdigest()
    return hex_dig
```

<sup>*Примечание: неуниверсальный вариант, будет работать только с конкретно Вашим типом строк*</sup>

Comment: А можно подробнее? Вот у меня есть код, как его исправить, чтобы он это использовал?

Comment: `import hashlib


def stdin_hash():
 text = input('Ввод: ').encode("utf-8")
 hash_object = hashlib.sha256(text)
 hex_dig = hash_object.hexdigest()
 return hex_dig


def main():
 while True:
  result = stdin_hash()
  print(result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
 main()`

Comment: @the4steps а что с этим кодом не так? Чем ожидаемый результат отличается от фактического?

Comment: @andreymal он берёт строку, а не сущность, и хеш от нее. А нужен хеш сущности.

Comment: @nomnoms12 ValueError: non-hexadecimal number found in fromhex() arg at position 0
  File "script_2.py", line 7, in stdin_hash
    char_b = bytearray.fromhex(hex_s).decode(

Comment: @the4steps что такое хеш строки? Что такое хеш сущности? Вообще, что такое сущность? Чем хеш строки отличается от хеша сущности? Поясните используемую вами терминологию, пожалуйста, ибо в питоне не существует термина «сущность». И скажите, откуда вы взяли хеш, который вы написали в тексте вопроса

Comment: @nomnoms12, посмотрел upd. Спасибо, но чёт по-прежнему не так работает. Заказчик уверяет, что хеш должен быть как я в вопросе написал.

Comment: Мол, я хеширую строку, а надо "сущность"

Comment: @the4steps Заказчик уточнил вид хэш-функции? Или может сказал, каким образом был получен её результат? В своём коде Вы используете `SHA256`, но для приведённого Вами смайлика её результат будет отличаться от того, что в вопросе.

Comment: @the4steps А что такое эта «сущность»? :D Как заметил andreymal, нет такого термина. Строка — это набор байтов, хэш от строки — хэш от набора байтов.

Comment: @the4steps вот значит уточните от заказчика, откуда он получил такой хеш. Иначе это получается заказ в стиле «принеси то не знаю что»

Comment: @nomnoms12 завтра заказчик скинет, где получил такой хеш, может понятнее станет

Comment: @the4steps а вы пока попробуйте своим кодом получить хеш вот этого смайлика 
 и сравните его с хешем из вопроса ;)

Comment: @andreymal ахах. Не пойму, то ли троллинг от заказчика, то ли заказчик ошибся.

Comment: @andreymal, а как вы догадались до такой неочевидной вещи?)

Comment: @the4steps тупо вбил этот хеш в гугл ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯